# whats the use of my places in android 4.3?

Tags: gps, 4.3-jelly-bean, geolocation, gps-tracking, location-services

I noticed there is my places under location services. It saves the office home and car location by a format I specify (wwfi bluetooth or map). 
 How is this used in android? Am I able to find my car location for example?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/2713925?hl=en):

> My Places gives you easy access to your important locations and
>   personal Maps history. Whether you’ve starred or searched on your
>   phone or computer, in My Places you’ll find your:
>
> - Offline Maps
> - Starred places (including Home and Work locations)
> - Recently viewed Maps items
> - Directions
> - Search queries
> - My Maps
> - Rated Places
> - Maps searches

Comment: That's the help for the Google Maps app, not the Android "My places" in the location services.

Answer (score 1):

From the Samsung support site:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000006/10628/127752

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Especially as the link is now dead and goes to the root of the support pages.